# Evaluating ln and exponential integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

$$I = \int_{0}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-\sqrt{Ax}}  \ln \left(1+x\right)}{\sqrt{x}} dx , \quad A>0.$$

Any hint for solving this integral, I think Gauss quadrature cannot be applied to this. Matlab is giving numerical answers to this, that means its solvable. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If it's giving numerical answers, it means that it converges. It doesn't mean there's a symbolic answer.

Comment: You can get an exact expression in terms of cosintegrals and sinintegrals. Is that what you ask for? If so, first integrate by parts.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Numerical quadratures will generally converge even if the integral is divergent. They won't converge when the total variation is very high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to finding
$$ g(B) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \log(1+x^2)\,e^{- B x}\,dx $$
for $B>0$, i.e. to finding the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $\log(1+x^2)$. By integration by parts we have
$$ g(B) = \frac{2}{B}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,e^{-B x}\,dx $$
and by partial fraction decomposition that equals
$$ \frac{2}{B}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(B)-\sin(B)\text{Si}(B)-\cos(B)\text{Ci}(B)\right] $$
where $\text{Si}$ and $\text{Ci}$ are the [sine/cosine integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). A numerical evaluation is indeed simpler from the previous integral representation, since both $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ and $e^{-Bx}$ are smooth and decreasing functions. For instance, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$ g(B)\leq\frac{2}{B}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\,dx}{(1+x^2)^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\,e^{-2B x}\,dx}=\frac{1}{B^2\sqrt{2}}. $$

Comment: Thanks alot Jack, can you help me with $g(B) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x\log(1+x^2)\,e^{- B x}\,dx$

Comment: @KanwalZaidi: same approach.